# スクレイピング結果をエクセルに出力したい

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping, selenium

アメブロのランキングをカテゴリー分けして、順位とタイトルをページが無くなるまでスクレイピングしたいのですが、エクセル出力がうまくいきません。
初心者で色々と間違っているのは自覚してますがご教授ください。

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

# ChromeのWebDriverオブジェクトを作成(ヘッドレスモードの場合)
# ノーヘッドレスの場合は引数なしで実行する
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
url = "https://blogger.ameba.jp/genres/t_variety/blogs/ranking"
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

def getTitle():
title = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")
rank = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("c-iconRank__rank")
#Loop

for titles, ranks in zip(title,rank):

el = ranks.text
el2 = titles.text
#print(el)
#print(el2)
#print("=====================================")
global df
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['順位','ブログ名'])
df_add = pd.Series([[el, el2]])
df = df.append(df_add, ignore_index = True)
#print(df)

def next_page():
# 次のページに移動する
  btn = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li.c-pager__item--next > a')
  btn.click()
  time.sleep(1)

def last_page():
  btn = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li.c-pager__item--next > a')
  if not btn:
    browser.quit()

def start():
  end = 2
  try:
    for page in range(end):
      getTitle()
  next_page()
  last_page()
finally:
  browser.quit()

# 次のページが無くなるまで
"""def start():
  while True:"""

start()

df.to_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='new_sheet_name', index=False)
```

Comment: 「うまくいかない」をもう少し具体的に説明することはできますか？例えばスクレイピングでのデータ取得自体は問題無いのに、エクセル出力の部分のみうまくいかない、もしくは実行時に○○とエラーが出てしまう、など / パッと見で気になるのはPandsを使用しているのに`import`が見当たらなかったり、インデントが適切でない箇所があるような気がします。

Answer (score 0):

一番の原因は `df` 関連の処理が色々と間違っていたことです。
特に `pd.Series()` のパラメータ指定方法ですね。以下になります。

```
df_add = pd.Series([el, el2], index=df.columns)
```

修正箇所をまとめると以下のようになります。

- 提示されたソースに import が無いので追加
- `chrome_options=` は古いので `options=` に変更
- `getTitle()` と `start()` の中身のインデントがおかしいので修正
- `df` の定義と初期化はグローバルに行うように移動
- `global df` を for ループの中ではなく、`getTitle()` の先頭に移動
- 上記 `pd.Series()` のパラメータ指定方法修正
- `next_page()` と `last_page()` は統合して１つにし、戻り値で次ページ有無(ループ継続か否か)を通知

修正結果を以下に示します。

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

# ChromeのWebDriverオブジェクトを作成(ヘッドレスモードの場合)
# ノーヘッドレスの場合は引数なしで実行する
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url = "https://blogger.ameba.jp/genres/t_variety/blogs/ranking"
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['順位','ブログ名'])

def getTitle():
  global df
  title = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")
  rank = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("c-iconRank__rank")
  #Loop
  for titles, ranks in zip(title,rank):
    el = ranks.text
    el2 = titles.text
    #print(el)
    #print(el2)
    #print("=====================================")
    df_add = pd.Series([el, el2], index=df.columns)
    df = df.append(df_add, ignore_index=True)

def next_page():
# 次のページに移動する
  btn = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li.c-pager__item--next > a')
  if not btn:
    return False
  btn.click()
  time.sleep(1)
  return True

def start():
  end = 2
  exists = False
  try:
    for page in range(end):
      getTitle()
      exists = next_page()
      if not exists:
        break
  finally:
    browser.quit()

start()

#print(df)
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name='new_sheet_name', index=False)
```